# Storing related data from POST request in API platform

Tags: api, symfony

I have a relation with User and Tags, When a user is created i have to pass associated tags for the user, ie  one to Many relation . I want to use the json post equest as below 
{
"name": "ABC",
"tags" : {
"Test", "Tag 1"
}
}  This should populate both the User and Tags table. How can i use this .

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to create a form and use CollectionsType in form for tags

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Comment: seems working. Also i tried normalization and de-normalization Groups in entity annotations. Works perfectly. Thanks